# How to determine if the input is of array type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

`<input type="text" name="members[0].name">
 <input type="text" name="members[0].address">`

```
Javascript code :

              var input_text;
              var inputs=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text],textarea, select");
                _.each(inputs, function(e, i) {
                    var keyName = $(e).attr("name");
                    if (typeof keyName != "undefined") {
                        var text = $(e).parent().find('label').text();

                        if ($(e).is('select')) {
                            input_text = input_text + "<tr><td>" + text + "</td><td>  " + $(e).find(':selected').text() + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        else {
                             input_text = input_text + "<tr><td>" + text + "</td><td>  " + $(e).val() + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }

                });
                console.log(input_text);
```

As You can see, I m getting the values of all the inputs in $(e).val() except those above mentioned inputs.

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you rephrase it please ?

Comment: I've edited my question .Hope that helps

Comment: Not really ... Sorry I really don't get what you want. If I only rely on your post name, then you can use `if (typeof yourVariable === 'Array')`

Comment: Thank You . I'll give it a try .I just want to read all the input fields and display the data that in a bootstrap model .

Answer (score 1):

Those inputs aren't an "array" in the browser. They just use a naming convention in their `name` which is used by some server-side handling (for instance, in PHP) to organize the form data for you when it's submitted.

I don't know what you mean by "previewing," but you can see the values of those elements by simply looping through the elements of your form (`yourForm.elements`), or by using `yourForm.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")` (or `$(yourForm).find("input[type=text]")` using jQuery — I missed the `jquery` tag on your question at first).

Example of `theForm.elements`:

```js
document.querySelector("form input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("the-form");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.elements, function(element) {
    if (element.type === "text") {
      console.log(element.name + " = " + element.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].name" value="name 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].address" value="address 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].name" value="name 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].address" value="address 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].name" value="name 2">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].address" value="address 2">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Show">
  </div>
</form>
```

Example of `theForm.querySelectorAll`:

```js
document.querySelector("form input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("the-form");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]"), function(element) {
    console.log(element.name + " = " + element.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].name" value="name 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].address" value="address 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].name" value="name 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].address" value="address 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].name" value="name 2">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].address" value="address 2">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Show">
  </div>
</form>
```

Example of `$(theForm).find`:

```js
$("form input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("the-form");
  $(form).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    console.log(this.name + " = " + this.value);
  });
  // Of course, we could have just used `$("#the-form input[type=text]").each`...
  // but I was assuming you'd already have `form`
});
```

```html
<form id="the-form">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].name" value="name 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[0].address" value="address 0">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].name" value="name 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[1].address" value="address 1">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].name" value="name 2">
  <input type="text" name="members[2].address" value="address 2">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Show">
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That really helps .Thank You ."Previewing" means I want display all the filled up data in a model before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to get the input type values using formID

```
 $('#formId input, #formId select').each(
        function(index){  
            var input = $(this);
        }
    );
```

OR

```
var formElements = new Array();
$("form :input").each(function(){
    formElements.push($(this));
});
```

OR

```
var $form_elements = $("#form_id").find(":input");
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray` or `serialize` for it .

```
$("form").serializeArray();
```

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. [Doc](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)